# Radial Basis Function (Gaussian) kernel question

Tags: machine-learning, kernel

I have followed the mathematics of the RBF kernel and understand how to show that the input space is mapped into an infinite-dimensional feature space. However, I'm struggling to make sense of the image below and others like it (in Andrew NG's online course, for example) which show two-dimensional data being mapped into three-dimensional space by the RBF kernel. How can this be if the mapping is to an infinite-dimensional feature space?

[image]

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63881/use-gaussian-rbf-kernel-for-mapping-of-2d-data-to-3d/63909

Comment: You have to provide the specific functions respectively the logic how the two graphs have been created. More specific than just a broad reference to some online course. Otherwise no one will be able give you a meaningful explanation. Have you had a look at user danica's comment in the answer you linked? He states the graphs are NOT showing mappings into infinite dimensional feature spaces and provides further links.

Comment: I missed danica's comment, thanks for pointing it out.